# In Elastic Search how can I get result from each types in an index for result limited to 10 query.?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have four types in my index and I am searching for a keyword and the result is limited to 10.I need to get records from all types.Is it possible.?

Comment: You could increase the size parameter, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean getting the first 10 docs per type, I'd use the multisearch API.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-multi-search.html